# Is it posibble to edit Named Credential url in a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, namedcredentials

I need to change the named credential url in the managed package. But it is not possible when we install the package in another org. Is there any possibility to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. [Editing Components and Attributes After Installation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm) has this to say about Named Credentials:

> ## Developer Editable
>
> - Endpoint
> - Label
>
> ## Subscriber and Developer Editable
>
> - Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Body
> - Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header
> - Auth Provider
> - Certificate
> - Generate Authorization Header
> - Identity Type
> - OAuth Scope
> - Password
> - Protocol
> - Username
>
> ## Locked
>
> - Name

As you can see, only the Developer is allowed to edit the endpoint/URL.

Comment: Thanks @sfdxfox. So I think I need to use remote site setting instead of Named Credentials.

Comment: @Prasad They have different purposes. Maybe you could have the subscriber define it as an unmanaged element, which your code should (theoretically) be able to access?

Comment: Oof glad I saw this. I'm working on a managed package project where definitely it was intended that the subscriber be able to edit a Named Credential endpoint. I guess we'll have to try another strategy.

Comment: So what is the point of allowing this in a managed package then? as package developer, you can't package a dynamic URL endpoint, and user can't edit to point it towards the org endpoint or am I understanding this incorrect?

Comment: @VarunC The reason why it can't be changed is because you may have a private API; if a subscriber can control the endpoint, they could reverse engineer your API by pointing to a server they control. If you need a Named Credential for what appears to be your use case, you could probably have the subscriber set one up after installation and then set a custom setting to use that Named Credential. As far as I'm aware, a managed package can call a Named Credential if it has the name.

Comment: I've looking into this since Lightning Components/LWC sessions don't allow Apex REST API execution, and the alternative seems to be to use Named Credentials to get access, but we can't package this due to URL not editable, so didn't proceed on this idea further.

Comment: @VarunC Right. You need to have your subscribers set up a Named Credential.

Comment: @VarunC and sfdcfox any insight into what the current best practice (or official Salesforce stance) on accessing Salesforce APIs from Lightning Components inside Managed Packages? Or what have you done? In his Mass Action Scheduler, Doug Ayers uses a Visualforce Page without clickjack protection to directly deploy the Connected App, Auth Provider, and Named Credential, but feel that turning off clickjack protection is not Salesforce Security a-okay.